# Multiple SSIDs with VLAN binding

Tags: router, vlan, ssid

I am seeking some advice surrounding the [EnGenius](http://www.engeniustech.com/) Long Range Wireless N Access Points, and Repeater products. I want to take the wireless signal from the main office, and extend it to surrounding buildings, and open areas.

I want to isolate/partition devices connecting wirelessly into three main SSIDs:

First SSID/VLAN - is to have the access point act as sort of a pass through; devices can connect directly to the router/gateway (192.168.1.1), this would be for employees/administrative.

Second SSID/VLAN - would allow devices to connect using IP 10.1.10.1, and be used for Guest/Customer access for Internet access only, I would like wireless isolation if possible.

Third SSID/VLAN - would be for a group of devices using IP 192.168.10.1, with access to Internet and printers.

If I were to use [ENH210EXT](http://www.engeniustech.com/business-networking/outdoor-access-points-client-bridges/16334-enh210ext) from the main router/gateway, considering that the access point supports multiple SSIDs with VLAN binding, would I be able to accomplish this? Are VLANs the appropriate route for this scenario? Can this be accomplished with a single router/gateway?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a switch that understands VLANs, you can assign a VLAN to each port on the switch, then whatever is plugged in to that port will use it like a normal LAN.  (You can do this with a linux gateway as well with the vconfig command.)